# Standard Excel function or write my own for the following string manipulation

Tags: sql, excel, replace

I have about 200 strings that I need to manipulate to make my SQL querying easier. Suppose I have a string like

> OR this.quantity LIKE 'transient' OR this.quantity LIKE 'gradient'

I would like to add wildcards to the beginning and end of 'transient' and 'gradient' as such:

> '%transient%', '%gradient%'

**Suppose further that I have about 198 more of these (unique of course).** Is there a function I can use for this manipulation or do I need to write my own VBA code to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you just find and replace `" '"` with `" '%"` and `"' "` with `"%' "` using space to determine whether it's the start or ending of a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using wildcards, so in SQL, you would just use `in`:

```
this.quantity IN ('transient', 'gradient')
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to add the wildcards - he must have forgotten them when he wrote the where strings.

Comment: I want to use wildcards

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit/replace, you'd have to get into text parsing formulas.  With your example above in A2, the formula to replace the first two quotes would be

```
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("'",A2))&"%" &MID(A2,SEARCH("'",A2)+1,SEARCH("'",A2,SEARCH("'",A2)+1)-SEARCH("'",A2))&"%"
```

Yes its ugly and I didn't write it from scratch.  Use the search function to find the '  Then put the text in.  The second ' is searching the same string, but using the place of the FIRST ' as the starting point; +1.   Not sure if it's the BEST way, but I've used Excel to do many text manipulations in the past.